# Java Swing drawing wrong pictures due to delay

Tags: java, swing, synchronization

I'm new to swing progarmming and im having some difficulties with the thread synchronisation.

I'm trying to iterate over an array and create a JPanel and a JFrame at every index and want to paint a picture on each panel. A picture which is related to the value stored in the array.
But all the frames/panels only hold the picture for the last array entry. I assume this is due to a seperate swing-Thread(?), but I dont know how to change it.
Can You help me?

```
package help;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingSynchro{

private JPanel jPanel;
private JFrame jFrame;
int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
int current;
private BufferedImage image1;
private BufferedImage image2;
private BufferedImage image3;
private BufferedImage image4;

public SwingSynchro(){

    //try{
    //    image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("someFilePath1.png"));
    //    image2 = ImageIO.read(new File("someFilePath2.png"));
    //    image3 = ImageIO.read(new File("someFilePath3.png"));
    //    image4 = ImageIO.read(new File("someFilePath4.png"));
    //} catch(IOException e){
    //    e.printStackTrace();
    //    System.out.println("wrong file path");
    //}// try catch

    for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){

        current = array[i];
            System.out.println("current Number: "+ current + " at array index:" +i);

            jPanel = new JPanel(){
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 6859593162185621113L;

                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                    super.paintComponent(g);

                    switch(current){
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("case 1");
                            //g.drawImage(image1, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("case 2");
                           // g.drawImage(image2, 20, 20, getWidth() - 40, getHeight() - 40, this);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("case 3");
                            //g.drawImage(image3, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            System.out.println("case 4");
                            //g.drawImage(image4, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("RELEASE THE KRAKEN!");
                            break;
                    }// switch
                }// paintComponent()
            };// anonymous class(extends JPanel)


        jFrame = new JFrame(String.valueOf(current));
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        jFrame.setSize(200, 250);
        jFrame.setLocation(i * 203, 0);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
}
```

I commented out the pictures because the console output you can clearly see that the drawImage method gets called after the whole for loop.

Edit: It looks like there is no other Thread, but in that case I dont understand why the drawings(or the case statements) have this delay. Can You explain to me why the code is not executed as usual.

Here is the output:

```
current Number: 1 at array index:0
current Number: 2 at array index:1
current Number: 3 at array index:2
current Number: 4 at array index:3
case 4
case 4
case 4
case 4
```

Comment: You talk about multi-threading but I see absolutely no multi-threading in your code at all. Am I missing something obvious? If so, please show it to me. Where's your `Runnable`? Where do you create this so-called background thread that you call `start()` on?

Comment: I was just assuming that there were asynch threads because it was the only explenation i had for that behavior.

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect. You will have background threads when you create one either directly or indirectly, and as I mentioned above, I see nowhere where you do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of instantiating the JPanel as an anonymous class, you could make it an inner class and use fields to hold the value of your `current` variable.

```
private static class CustomJPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6859593162185621113L;
    private final int current;

    private CustomJPanel(int current) {
        this.current = current;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);

        switch(current){
            case 1:
                System.out.println("case 1");
                //g.drawImage(image1, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("case 2");
                // g.drawImage(image2, 20, 20, getWidth() - 40, getHeight() - 40, this);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("case 3");
                //g.drawImage(image3, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("case 4");
                //g.drawImage(image4, 10, 10, getWidth() - 20, getHeight() - 20, this);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("RELEASE THE KRAKEN!");
                break;
        }// switch
    }// paintComponent()
}
```

and then just instantiate it as

```
jPanel = new CustomJPanel(current);
```

This way, you're making sure that it's been passed the value that the `current` variable had when the JPanel was instantiated.

Comment: I prefer writing inner classes to anonymous classes whenever they're longer than 5 lines. As for the constructor parameters, I believe it is the right (and thread-safe) way to go since you do indeed need the value of the `current` variable at the time of instantiation of your JPanel. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @Enum: there's nothing wrong with Zoltan's coding, and in fact this is often used commonly and effectively (as he shows). 1+.

Comment: thanks guys, i still have some trouble with the real code(the soulution worked perfect for this example though!) but it's 4 am and i need to sleep now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Swing is single threaded. Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) if you want to see updates to your GUI in real time.